# tkFileDialog.askopenfilename adding trash on filenames

Tags: python, windows

I have the following code:

```
csv_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title="Select csv directory",initialdir=default_initial_dir)
print csv_path
```

And I have the following behaivours in different computers:

In one computer, with Python 2.7.3 and Windows XP 32 bits I get the following output selecting 2 files:

- {C:/Temp/MMA/Run_A1/V4.0/Geoflow-2b_Run1a_DOY353_aa1hfaa_csv/MMA_OPS_1039899108851.csv}
- {C:/Temp/MMA/Run_A1/V4.0/Geoflow-2b_Run1a_DOY353_aa1hfaa_csv/MMA_OPS_1039899108852.csv}

In another computer with Windows 7 64 bits and Python 2.7.2 i get the following:

- C:/Temp/MMA/Run_A1/V4.0/Geoflow-2b_Run1a_DOY353_aa1hfaa_csv/MMA_OPS_1039899108851.csv
- C:/Temp/MMA/Run_A1/V4.0/Geoflow-2b_Run1a_DOY353_aa1hfaa_csv/MMA_OPS_1039899108852.csv

As you can see, in the XP machine I'm getting an extra {} on the string, and for example, if I run the following code on that machine

```
csv_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title="Select csv directory",initialdir=default_initial_dir).split()
for f in csv_list:
    file = open(f,'r')
    calculate_column_numbers(file)
    process_tm_file(file)
    log("%s\r" % (str(i)+' of '+str(len(csv_list))),False)
    file.close()
```

I will get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: u'{C:/Temp/MMA/Run_A1/V4.0/Geoflow-2b_Run1a_DOY353_aa1hfaa_csv/MMA_OPS_1039899108851.csv}'
```

Which is totally spected looking at the string we have on the first place since the askdirectory method is adding me that extra {}

Why am I getting that {}?

Comment: Can you print `type(csv_path)` as well?

Comment: @mgilson On both computers I get the following: **<type 'unicode'>**

Comment: In Linux I get a <type 'tuple'>... I cannot understand why the same code has three different behaviours in three different systems

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you're using `askdirectory` when you really want is `askopenfilename`.  It's possible that using the correct function will clear this up.  In the code snippet you posted, you have a variable `csv_path` which is returned from `askdirectory` and then a variable `csv_list` which is iterated over to give you something to open.  You should probably clear that one up as well...

Comment: @mgilson, Sorry misstyped it, It is indeed **askopenfilename**, copied wrong line from script, I'm going to correct it on the code